# If a person is from Parashara gotra but the girl he loves is of Vasishta gotra, are they siblings?

Tags: marriage, gotra

If a person is from Parashara gotra but the girl he loves is of Vasishta gotra, are they siblings? (Since Parashara was the grandson of Vasishta) So the question arises: are the gotras belonging to the same lineage *sagotras*?

Comment: A marriage is to be avoided in that case, I have however seen such marriages in the case of emergency

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi So are they the same gotras?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the pravaras associated with the two gotras as marriage rules are based on pravara associated with gotra eg: [mahAbhArata anushasana parva CIV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b069.htm) :

> *A woman of the **same Pravaras** should also be avoided*

Some of the shrautasutras associated with vedas contain a section called "pravaradhyaya" which provides details of pravaras associated with gotras and their marriage rules.

[This book](https://archive.org/details/earlybrahmanicalsystemsofgotraanpravaragotrapravaramanjariofpurshottamajohnbroughoup_202003_875_K/page/n21/mode/1up) contains an excerpt of those sections from shrauta sutras and matsyapurANa. [chapter VII](https://archive.org/details/earlybrahmanicalsystemsofgotraanpravaragotrapravaramanjariofpurshottamajohnbroughoup_202003_875_K/page/n94/mode/1up) of this book has details of gotras having "vashishta" as one of their pravaras and marriage rules associated with them.

Similar details are also mentioned in [skandapurANa-dharmaranyakhanDa-ch21](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423642.html) :

> *8. There is no marriage if there is similarity of Pravaras in five or three sages.(If there is similarity of three sages i.e. if ṃree
> Pravaras are common, where five sages constitute the Pravaras, no
> marriage can take place.) If there is similarity of two sages where
> three sages constitute the Pravaras then also there is a ban. So is
> the case of Bhṛgu and Aṅgiras. In the remaining cases, even if one
> sage is common the ban is to be enforced.*

Comment: So that means they are the same gotras? (Sagotra)

Comment: As per above references, they will belong to the same spiritual lineage if pravara - vashishta is present in both gotras.

Comment: yes multiple persons can have the same name, thats exactly the reason why pravara has to be checked along with gotra as per rules. Eg: harita gotra (pravara: angiras, ambarisha, youvanasva) found in south india is different from harita gotra (pravara: vashishta) found in north india and hence marriage is possible between these two haritas as pravaras are different.

Comment: So is marriage between parashara and Vasishta possible?

Comment: you will have to check pravara to verify, I dont know their pravaras.

Comment: Thanks. Your help meant a lot!

Comment: I had one more small doubt. Why is Parashara gotra began of there was already Vasishta gotra. Which was obviously famous and recognised

Comment: Distinguished rishis are usually given new gotra status

Comment: Yeah, so why was is it given a status of new gotra? So that it is considered different from Vasishta and therefore marriage between the 2 gotras to be possible?

Comment: marriage will be prohibited due to sameness of pravara "vashishta" as per above references. New gotra status is for some vedic ritual roles which are restricted as per gotra.

Comment: Can marriage happen between two people with pravara of Vasishta Maitravaruna Kaundinya   AND Vasishta Shaktya Parashara?

Comment: You can find out from the book referenced.

Comment: The book does not mention about this. Also I would like to tell, that in Matsya purana,even though Parashara is known as grandson of Vasishta, the family of Parashara is given separately after Vasishta. In it, it is mentioned that "the Vasishta's shouldn't intermarry" in the Vasishta section, and "Parasharas shouldn't intermarry" in the parasara section. This raises a question that, can Parasaras marry vasishta?