# Is it possible that a person of Parashara gotra and a person of Vasishta gotra are not related?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, gotra

Both Vasishta and Parashara come under and share the common pravara of "Vasishta" are the people of these gotras related? Or could they marry each other?

Comment: Can someone please answer this question. It is very important. I don't want this question to be lost in this site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a person is from Parashara gotra but the girl he loves is of Vasishta gotra, are they siblings?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/if-a-person-is-from-parashara-gotra-but-the-girl-he-loves-is-of-vasishta-gotra)